# Why $\sin(\pi)$ sometimes equal to $0$?

Tags: trigonometry

> Simplify the statements. Which variables are free and which are bound?
>   If the statement has no free variable, find out if the statement is
>   true or false. Justify your answer.

This was the assignment I had.
Now, one of the statements was this:
$$\pi \in\{ x \in \mathbb{R} | \sin(x) = 0\}$$

that I solved saying that it's not true, since this equation $\sin(\pi) = 0$ is not true, but I am wrong, because the correct answer was `true` and not `false`.

Why is $\sin(\pi) = 0$ true? Shouldn't $\sin(x) = 0$ be true, only if $x = 0$ or $x = 180$ or multiples?

Comment: In mathematics, $\sin$ is almost *always* the function given by
$$\sin(x) = \frac1{2i} (e^{ix} - e^{-ix})$$
Wich takes arguments in radians. Thus $\sin(k\pi) = 0 \ \forall\ k\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are calculating in degrees, then $\sin (\pi)$ is  not $0$, but in radians, $\pi$ radians is equal to $180$ degrees, so $\sin(\pi)=0$. Usually, in mathematics (and also in technical sciences), radians are used much more than degrees, so if you only see an expression like $$\sin(1.343),$$
then it is safe to assume that you are calculating in radians. If you are calculating in degrees, then the "degree" symbol is used. This means that, in the usual notation, $$\sin(\pi)=0$$
is true, but $$\sin(\pi^\circ)=0$$ is false.

Comment: She/he didn't specify it because in mathematics, radians are used by default.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of $\pi$ is understood to be in radians, then you can simply deduce that $\sin(\pi) = 0 $. In fact, $$ \sin(n\pi) = 0 $$ for any *integer* $n$.